# Find difference between two arrays considering duplicates

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to compare two arrays of hashes, and delete old records. `stale_records` are records from `old_records` that don't exist in `new_records`. Items in the array can be duplicated.

```
old_records = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
new_records = [{a: 1}]
stale_records = #=> [{:b=>2}]

old_records = [{a: 1}, {a: 1}]
new_records = [{a: 1}]
stale_records #=> [{a: 1}]
```

I am wondering if there an efficient way for a few million records.

I tried:

```
old_records = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}]
new_records = [{a: 1}]
stale_records = old_records - new_records #=> [{:b=>2}]

old_records = [{a: 1}, {a: 1}]
new_records = [{a: 1}]
stale_records = old_records - new_records #=> []
```

which does not give the correct result when items are duplicated.

Comment: It'd help us if you gave an example of "cleanly handle" :) if ruby worked the way you'd like it to, what would you have to write?

Comment: I guess efficient would be a better word. The way I initially thought of handling it was to loop through each element of one array and compare/delete it from the other separately rather than using subtraction.

Comment: Agree with above, what do you expect to be stored in stale_records?

Comment: sorry, updated the question :)

Comment: Hmmm, when it comes to efficiencies over a few million records... I start thinking of "can I do this in the database itself"... have you looked into what SQL can offer you?